# Where does Java Project Explorer load files from in Eclispe IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, csproj

I'm a .Net guy and used to csproj/vbproj files being the central repository for all folders/files in a .Net project.

What's the equivalent in Java explorer in Eclipse IDE? Where does it store the folders/resources and their physical paths etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few files involved. `.project` and `.classpath` cover the main important features, and the `.settings` directory includes project-specific settings (e.g. different compiler warning levels etc).

Note that unlike Visual Studio solutions, Eclipse doesn't specify each and every file to compile: it assumes that if there's a `.java` file underneath a source folder, it should be compiled. This makes life a *lot* easier in terms of diffs to project files... once set up, the project files in Eclipse rarely change, whereas they change every time someone adds or removes a file in Visual Studio :(

Comment: Thx for the quick update! Do you know what folder they go to?

Comment: Way too fast for my typing ;-)

Comment: Well, actually, ignore my previous edit. I kind of got the answer I was looking for. 

This "implicit" folder-file relationship was the puzzle I was trying to solve :)